# Mockk function called on class definition

Tags: kotlin, mockk

How to mock a function that is called on a class definition?

```
class Handler {
    private val loggingOnly = config("loggingOnly", false)

    fun cancelAccount(account: Account){
        if(!loggingOnly) account.cancel() 
    }
}
```

I've mocked the function outside the class context and it does work.

```
@Test
fun `test action should not be taken if loggingOnly is true`() {
    mockkStatic("pckg.ConfigurationKt")
    every { config<Boolean>("loggingOnly", false) } returns true
    assertTrue(config("loggingOnly", false))
}
```

But when I try to mock it for my class I end up with the account canceled

```
@Test
fun `test action should not be taken if loggingOnly is true`() {
    mockkStatic("pckg.ConfigurationKt")
    every { config<Boolean>("loggingOnly") } returns true

    val account = mockk<Account>()
    val handler = Handler()

    handler.cancelAccount(account)

    verify(exactly = 0) { account.cancel(account) }
}
```

I suspect the config function is called before my mock, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake.

My class is calling

```
config("loggingOnly", false)
```

I should mock

```
every { config<Boolean>("loggingOnly", false) } returns true
```

or

```
every { config<Boolean>("loggingOnly", any()) } returns true
```